# MySQL limit 5 per month

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I try to show the 'top 5' per month of worked hours.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    concat(m.firstname, " ",m.lastname) AS name,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(pl.end_activity,pl.start_activity)))) AS activity,
    month(start_activity) AS month,
    year(start_activity) AS year
FROM 
    log AS pl
INNER JOIN
    employee AS m
ON
    m.employee = pl.employee
GROUP BY
    name,
    year,
    month,
ORDER BY
    year,
    month,
    activity
```

I tried: limit 0,5 bit it gives me only the first 5 records of all. How can I show 5 records ordered by month?

Comment: What is your MySQL Server version ? Do you have access or can upgrade to latest version (8.0.2 and above) ?

Comment: I’ve the latest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL version 8.0.2 and above, we can utilize [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html). We can utilize [`Row_Number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) window function to determine row numbers within a partition of **concatenated expression of year and month**. Ordering within the partition is done based on the descending order of `activity`.

We can then use this result-set as a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and consider row number up-to 5. This will give us 5 rows per month, having top `activity` values.

```
SELECT dt.* 
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    concat(m.firstname, " ",m.lastname) AS name,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(pl.end_activity,pl.start_activity)))) AS activity,
    month(start_activity) AS month,
    year(start_activity) AS year, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(year(start_activity), month(start_activity))
                       ORDER BY SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(pl.end_activity,pl.start_activity)))) DESC) AS row_no 
  FROM 
    log AS pl
  INNER JOIN
    employee AS m
  ON
    m.employee = pl.employee
  GROUP BY
    name,
    year,
    month
) AS dt 
WHERE dt.row_no <= 5
ORDER BY
    dt.year,
    dt.month,
    dt.activity
```